# What 'synchronous' means in JavaScript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous

This concerns  Javascript & PHP specifically. i have read that both of these are "synchronous languages" (unless using AJAX calls in the case of Javascript)

I have always assumed that this means one line of code will **always wait** for the previous line of code to finish before processing.

**In Javascript**

```
$('#box').fadeOut();
$('#box2').css("background-color", "orange");
```

`box 2` should only turn orange after `box` has faded out.

```
var tags = <div class='tags'></div>;
var box = $('#box');
box.append(tags);
if (box.css("display") == 'block') {
    box.find('#alert').text("Arrived");
}
```

`if` should only execute after `box.append(tags)`

**In PHP**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    array[] = $row['BoxName'];
}

if (count($array) == 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    array[] = $row['Box2Name'];
}}
```

`if (count($array) == 0)` should only run **after** the first `while loop` has finished.

Comment: No, you should check the jQuery manual on `fadeOut()`. Where the php is concerned, yes.

Comment: So fadeOut() may have other repercussions, but the php case is definitely correct?

Comment: There are no *repercussions*, it simply is asynchronous.

Comment: I see, thanks. Anyway, I added another Javascript example. In any case, both PHP and javascript will definitely execute line by line unless there are asynchronous effects or methods employed, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but when you work with asynchronous javascript you should use the callback functions or use promises to make sure your code executes when it has to.